# Deploying a web project in Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am trying to run my web application in Tomcat server 7.0_68. When I run the startup.bat no errors were shown in the tomcat console. But after i deploy my web project in tomcat manager it shows the following errors.

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/ALinguist]
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.ja
va:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection
.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.ja
va:735)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.j
ava:863)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
5)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 01, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart

SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in op
ening zip file
        at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.ja
va:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardConte
xt.java:5197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
5)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 01, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngin
e[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ALinguist]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
5)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5387)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more

Mar 01, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive G:\software\apache-tomcat-7.0.68
\webapps\ALinguist.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catal
ina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].Stan
dardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ALinguist]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:903)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
5)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
```

Does anybody know what is the reason for this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493931/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-or-unreadable-war-file-error-in-op)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a Java Web Application (.war) on tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217693/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-war-on-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link given in comments.

But if you are using `linux` then make sure it is readable. You can check by `Run "chmod +r"` to the `war` file to give read rights to everyone.